# Recognize when user close a window (when click on close button)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

How can i recognize when user close a window ?

i want to do something before window close.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use it in a viewcontroller

```
//initWithNibName

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowWillClose:) name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification object:self.view.window];
```

---

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        NSWindow *win = [notification object];
        //...
    }
```

Comment: or you can set your `NSWindowController` as a `NSWindowsDelegate` and do `[self.window setDelegate:self]` and add `- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification` in your controller class.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your custom class to conform to `NSWindowDelegate` protocol.

Set an instance of your custom class to be the delegate of your window

Then use one of these methods (probably the windowWillClose: one) to do something before the window closes.

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in every NSViewController
Returning true will close the window, false will not close it.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {
    
    var firstWindow:NSWindow?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firstWindow = NSApplication.shared.windows.first
        firstWindow?.delegate = self
    }
        
    func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        // Do something appropriate here

        print("Window Should Close")
        return false
    }
}
```